# How to convert ^ symbol to html superscript?

Tags: php, html

I have a string

```
The expression (a + b + c)^2 - (a + b - c)^2 + (a - b + c)^2 + ( b + c - a)^2
```

how to convert ^2 to <sup>2</sup>

```
<p>The expression (a + b + c)<sup>2</sup> + (a + b - c)<sup>2</sup> + (a - b + c)<sup>2</sup> + ( b + c - a)<sup>2</sup> + equals ________</p>
```

using html or php?

Comment: Should it work with brackets? (a+b)^(c+d)

Answer (score 3):

[`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is your friend:

```
$str = "The expression (a + b + c)^2 - (a + b - c)^2 + (a - b + c)^2 + ( b + c - a)^2";

echo preg_replace("/\^([^\s]+)/","<sup>$1</sup>", $str);
```

The result is The expression (a + b + c)<sup>2</sup> - (a + b - c)<sup>2</sup> + (a - b + c)<sup>2</sup> + ( b + c - a)<sup>2</sup>

The `\^([^\s]+)` pattern matches `^` and everything after it until it meets a space. So `1^0.99` will change to 1<sup>0.99</sup>, `(a+b)^(c+d)` will turn into (a+b)<sup>(c+d)</sup> and even `hello^banana` will be transformed into hello<sup>banana</sup>.

Comment: "The expression (a + b + c)^2 - (a + b - c)^2 + (a - b + c)^2 + ( b + c - a)^2 + hello^banana + 1^0.99"

Comment: the result will be like this - The expression (a + b + c)2 - (a + b - c)2 + (a - b + c)2 + ( b + c - a)2 + hello<sup>a</sup> + 1<sup>9</sup>

Comment: Make sure it's `\^([^\s]+)`, not `\^([^\s])+`, I had a typo in there

Comment: and one more quetion, i have a string "testing testing test.png testing", in that string how to find test.png and replace with <img src='/uploads/test.png'>

Comment: according to Stack Overflow question standards you should open a new question if you have a problem like this. Why did you mark another answer as correct, if it doesn't work with `1^0.99`?

Comment: Sry boss, but i reached limit my quetions, plz help me.

Comment: when i ask new quetion it says You have reached your question limit, what should i do? @Nordenheim

Comment: px^3+x^2-2x-q  it will display like this  px<sup>3+x^2-2x-q</sup>, i want like this 3+x<sup>2</sup>+x<sup>2</sup>-2x-q @Nordenheim

Comment: My answer states: The `\^([^\s]+)` pattern matches `^` and everything after it until it meets a **space**. So, add space before a `+`: `px^3 + x^2 - 2x - q`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex in PHP to replace the pattern:

```
<?php
$msg = '(a + b + c)^2 - (a + b - c)^2 + (a - b + c)^2 + ( b + c - a)^2';
$msg = preg_replace('#\^([0-9]+)#','<sup>$1</sup>',$msg);
echo $msg;
?>
```

This will write the following:

```
(a + b + c)<sup>2</sup> - (a + b - c)<sup>2</sup> + (a - b + c)<sup>2</sup> + ( b + c - a)<sup>2</sup>
```

Comment: for example ^0.99, then how to change the preg expression?